# How to detect if keepalive is enabled on TCP socket in AIX and Solaris?

Tags: sockets, tcp, keep-alive

I am working on a solution where i am enabling keepalive option on the TCP socket. On linux I am able to see if keepalive is enabled or not using netstat

*netstat -o -p |grep processid*

ouput is as follows

> $ netstat -o
>
> Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
>
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address        State       **Timer**
>   tcp        0      0 himanshu-laptop.l:46096
>   sjc-not16.sjc.dropb:www ESTABLISHED **off (0.00/0/0)**
>   tcp       38 
>   0 himanshu-laptop.l:40156 v-d-1a.sjc.dropbo:https CLOSE_WAIT  **off
>   (0.00/0/0)**
>   tcp       38      0 himanshu-laptop.l:54501
>   v-client-5a.sjc.d:https CLOSE_WAIT  **off (0.00/0/0)**

In command output I see field timer which shows *off* or *keepalive*.

But I am not able to get this on AIX and Solaris.
Want to check how to get this information on AIX and Solaris?

Comment: Thank you for this piece of information (regaring linux). For AIX, use `lsof` with option `-Tf` eg `lsof -nPi -Tf` and check for `SO=KEEPALIVE=cnt`

Comment: Why? You can tell from the `setsockopt()` return value whether it succeeded or not. Why do you need to know from outside the process?

Comment: @user207421: It might be needed for administrative reasons; for example Oracle (without proper configuration) opens connections without TCP_KEEPALIVE, which might lead to "half-open/half-dead" connections that never actually terminate.

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond: Thanks for the help. Above mentioned command worked in AIX but lsof is not present in solaris. Yes we need to check this from outside the process.
Is there any alternative for solaris?

Comment: Just compile `lsof` from source.

Comment: netstat --timers -tn|grep keepalive